# Routing problem with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use meta_search for global search and models search.

for models search, in index file of the model. i create a form_for with this code.

```
<%= form_for @search, :url => building_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :city %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

my model controller have this code

```
def index
@search = Building.search(params[:search])
@buildings = @search.all
end
```

But, when i try to show the index for my building, i have this error message

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Buildings#index

Showing /Users/stephanebaribeau/Sites/cadifice/app/views/buildings/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"buildings"}

Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <h1>Listing buildings</h1>
2:  
3: 
4: <%= form_for @search, :url => building_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
5:   <%= f.label :name %>
6:   <%= f.text_field :city %>
7:   <%= f.submit %>
```

my routes.rb have this
    resources :buildings do
    resources :floors
    end

i tried without plurial, same error.

my rake routes give me that

```
       building_floors GET    /buildings/:building_id/floors(.:format)            {:controller=>"floors", :action=>"index"}
                       POST   /buildings/:building_id/floors(.:format)            {:controller=>"floors", :action=>"create"}
    new_building_floor GET    /buildings/:building_id/floors/new(.:format)        {:controller=>"floors", :action=>"new"}
   edit_building_floor GET    /buildings/:building_id/floors/:id/edit(.:format)   {:controller=>"floors", :action=>"edit"}
        building_floor GET    /buildings/:building_id/floors/:id(.:format)        {:controller=>"floors", :action=>"show"}
                       PUT    /buildings/:building_id/floors/:id(.:format)        {:controller=>"floors", :action=>"update"}
                       DELETE /buildings/:building_id/floors/:id(.:format)        {:controller=>"floors", :action=>"destroy"}
             buildings GET    /buildings(.:format)                                {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"index"}
                       POST   /buildings(.:format)                                {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"create"}
          new_building GET    /buildings/new(.:format)                            {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"new"}
         edit_building GET    /buildings/:id/edit(.:format)                       {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"edit"}
              building GET    /buildings/:id(.:format)                            {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"show"}
                       PUT    /buildings/:id(.:format)                            {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"update"}
                       DELETE /buildings/:id(.:format)                            {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"destroy"}
```

whats wrong with my routes? 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the url to `buildings_path` instead of `building_path` like this:

```
 <%= form_for @search, :url => buildings_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **building_path** in your **form_for** line, which will take you to the **buildings/:id** i.e. show page. You should use **buildings_path**, which takes you to the **index** page.